# 500 Internal Server Error Hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

I have a websites on a hosting websites but a single web is giving 500 internal error I don't know what to do i have set the php flag here is my .htacces file code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting E_ALL
```

Comment: check your logs and why is this tagged as php?

Comment: You have to really ask your hosting company, as it differs on each server and some hosting companies prohibit totally from changing the `php.ini`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have changed the tag to apache. Can add PHP as well, tbh.

Comment: Check your access logs.

Comment: but the other web that are hosted on that web is doing okay @Soolie

Comment: Okay, in that case, you really need to check the access logs.

Comment: where is it located

Comment: @Soolie Maybe the php tag was a suggestive tag when the OP used the .htaccess tag, that I can't speak for them but it is a possibility and they didn't bother answering my comment, to which was the first one in. They responded to you instead.

Comment: Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved It by changing by the permission from 777 to 755 of the website root folder